# Archive counter increasing every time I publish a blog post

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, orchardcms

Every time I publish a blog post, the archive counter sees that as a new item to archive.

I think this might be a bigger problem though. If I have an existing blog post and want to make changes, pressing "save" does not save the changes. I have to go and actually publish the post again. Is there a way around this? Is there something I'm not doing in the content type definition?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Pressing save does save the changes (in a draft), but doesn't publish it, until you press publish. What is the exact issue?

Comment: If I publish a post initially, the archive counter increases by 1. If I want to make changes to that same post, I'll have to save the changes and then publish again (increasing the archive count by 1).

Comment: Do you mean saving does not create a new draft once the post has been published, or that you're surprised that saving creates a draft instead of modifying the already published post?

Comment: Saving creates a new draft and I know it modifies an existing post but every time I want to publish those changes the archive counter increases by one. What I want to do is save edits to a post without increasing the archive counter

Comment: Why? How does increasing the archive counter affect you?

Comment: It says there were 16 posts posted in February but in reality it's 4. I don't want it to display an incorrect number.

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy I would appreciate if you could close the loop on this for me please!

Comment: This is this bug: https://github.com/OrchardCMS/Orchard/issues/5775

Comment: Got it. Any idea when it'll be resolved?